# Add a click event to a listbox filled with objects in code

Tags: c#, wpf, events, contextmenu

I'm trying to sho a contextmenu on right-click on an item in a listbox. So i'm binding a list of "Users" to my listbox. Then i'm a bit lost. I thought i could foreach the list and add a mouserightdown event on the listboxitems, but i can't figure out how.

Is this a good way, or does anyone know a better way of accomplishing what i want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just set the ListBox.ContextMenu property.  See http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=92

Comment: that's it, so easy ... in the meanwhile, i have made a usercontrol, cause i know you can add an event to it, but this is just what i needed


Can you post this as answer, i want to accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2 things that may solve the problem you are experiencing :

1) If you use usercontrols to fill your listbox, you can add click events to it.

2) If you add a contextmenu to your listbox, right-clicking an item will automatically open the contextmenu, so you don't have to add a click event to it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
        private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(p);
            contextMenuStrip1.Show();
        }
    }
```

Edit: a bit too late sry ;)

Comment: Nice, almost the same code :D, except I am not sure how this works in WPF.

Comment: In your XAML, you have to define the MouseDown or OrMouseDown event. It's pretty much like non-WPF code.

Comment: it's dynamic, cannot put an event to a listboxitem or whatever, it is depending on the items, so putting it in XAML will not work

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can get in the Mousdown Event from the Listbox, witch Item is selected.
Or do you do the right click without have a item selected?

Comment: the events don't work when clicking on a listboxitem, only when u click on white space...

I want to right-click on an item in the list, and showing a context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I did this, but if I remember correctly:

- You should trigger the event on right-mouse-down
- Figure out the location of the cursor at that time
- Ask the listbox, which item sits at those coordinates.

The listbox does have a method for that I think...

Edit:
Here, have some code:

```
    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            return;

        int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);

        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.Items[index].ToString());

    }
```

Obviously, you need to add some error checking, if there is an item at that point etc.

Comment: euhm, why not just use MouseRightButtonDown instead of checking which button is clicked...?

btw, i'm working in wpf, and it seems it doesn't have indexfrompoint

Comment: because you doesn't say that you use WPF. Maybe there is something different.

Answer (score 0):

This will answer your question I think:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2c8f00ca-9c7d-4237-b2cf-f60911a008a9

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        Point p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(p);
        contextMenuStrip1.Show();
    }
}
```